# Animation rotation in unity3D is not as accurate as it in maya

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, rotation, maya

I have a turn on spot animation that actually turns the player 61 degrees in maya. But when import the animation to unity and apply it to a animator controller to control a character, it turns the character 56 degrees. Why the turn angles are different?

Answer (score 0):

Maya and some other 3D packages export their models with `Z`-axis faces upward. Standard scripts in Unity assume the `Y`-axis represents up in your world axis. It is better to fix the rotation in Unity than to modify the scripts to make things fit.

[How do I fix the rotation of an imported model?](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-FixZAxisIsUp.html)

The same problem refers to orientation in Unity:

[Rotation and Orientation in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html)

[image]

See also [Euler vs Quaternion](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/3PP-MAYA-MAS-Wiley/files/GUID-1C18589A-B2EF-4FDF-9925-783D9A17FCAA-htm.html) and [The order of transformation in Maya](http://www.utdallas.edu/atec/midori/Handouts/order_of_transformation.htm).

Comment: I'd also check out the animation import settings - is the animation playing it's whole length? Are there any interpolation or key frame reductions settings? Was the whole animation exported?